# Why PHP Session is Empty Even After session_start()?

Tags: php, session, php-8

I just upgraded the existing version of Apache to 2.4 and MySQL to 8.0. After this upgrade I am facing a strange issue with PHP.

PHP `$_SESSION` remains an empty array even after calling `session_start()` function. Here is the code snippet from my PHP file.

```
session_start();

if(session_id() != ''){
    echo '<script>alert("session is active")</script>';
}
else{
    echo '<script>alert("'.json_encode($_SESSION).'")</script>';
}
```

[image]

Here you can see the javascript alert with empty array.

Did anyone ever face such issue?

another if condition check in file also returning true.

```
if ($token != $_SESSION[Codes::FORM_TOKEN_ELEMENT]) {
        header("location:index.php?msg=inft&auth=" . urlencode(CryptoJsAes::encryptData(0)));
        die;
    }
```

Here `$token` has value but `$_SESSION[Codes::FORM_TOKEN_ELEMENT]` does not.

I tried below code at the top of the page

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["ID"])) {
    echo "Session Started";
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["ID"] = rand(78273874,922839929928839);
}
```

`!isset($_SESSION["ID"])` is always returning true

Comment: Maybe check the return value of `session_start()`. Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas, the issue is resolved after changing permissions on default `session` directory in `/var/lib/php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved after changing permissions on default session directory in  `/var/lib/php`. I ran following command to resolve this issue.

```
chmod -R 777 session
```